# grep & wget in conflict via variable

Tags: xml, bash, variables, grep, wget

I just got this error when trying to rewrite my code.

This code works as expected:

```
#XML downloading
wget -q http://192.168.50.154/details.xml -O details.xml

#load XML in Variable
rohxml=details.xml

#Read Data and save to Variable
health=$(grep '<Health' $rohxml | cut -f2 -d">"|cut -f1 -d"<")
```

But when I try to save it directly to a variable (because I can't save a new file in the new server) it throws me the following error:

> grep: invalid option -- 'O'
>   Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
>   Try 'grep --help' for more information.

This is the "new" code:

```
#load XML in Variable
ABFRAGE="'wget -q -O- http://192.168.50.154/details.xml'"
rohxml=$ABFRAGE

#Read Data and save to Variable
health=$(grep '<Health' $rohxml | cut -f2 -d">"|cut -f1 -d"<")
```

Comment: You do know you're storing the wget command line in a variable and then executing it on the grep command line rather than saving the output of the command in a variable, right? Don't do that - that's what functions are for. As written you're exposing yourself to nasty surprises when you run it from certain directories, etc. as you're exposing your command to the shell for wildcard expansion, globbing, word splitting, etc.

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the title. To indicate that your question has been answered, accept an answer (usually you'll want to upvote it as well). If none of the existing answers solved your problem, you can post and accept an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some basic misunderstandings of how shell works. Try this:

```
rohxml="$( wget -q -O- 'http://192.168.50.154/details.xml' )"
health="$( awk -F'[<>]' '/<Health/{ print $3 }' <<<"$rohxml" )"
printf 'health="%s"\n' "$health"
```

and then ask if you have questions. I'm assuming you have some use for the variables `rohxml` and `health` beyond the code you posted otherwise all you need is:

```
wget -q -O- 'http://192.168.50.154/details.xml' |
awk -F'[<>]' '/<Health/{ print $3 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You stored the string

```
'wget -q -O- http://192.168.50.154/details.xml'
```

in the $rohxml variable, not the output of the command. Use backquotes to store the output.

Moreover, to extract information from XML, use an XML aware tool. For simple queries, `xmllint` should work well enough.

Comment: Now I have
    ABFRAGE="`wget -q -O- http://192.168.50.154/details.xml`"

But now its not parsing the commands correctly (I get errors from the other XML stuff which I'm not putting through grep)

Comment: @MrPoPoPolski You need to use `var=$(command)` instead. Also you will want to enclose the variable in double quotes in your `grep` command

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrote my code again and now just use the following and it's working fine

```
wget -O - -o /dev/null  http://192.168.50.154/details.xml | sed -n 's:.*<Health>\(.*\)</Health>.*:\1:p'
```